# Vertical query with \G dont work

Tags: mysql

I try use this example:
https://makandracards.com/makandra/7811-mysql-shell-vertical-vs-horizontal-layout

```
SELECT * FROM users;

SELECT * FROM users \G
```

But the \G dont work:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\G' at line 1".

Why don't work?
Exist another way?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: stupid question (maybe), but you are using the mysql command line interface?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `--vertical` option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_vertical

Comment: Friends, thanks! the problem was the what mnagel says, I was doing this in the mysqlguitools software, i open the command line and works fine, but my doubt now is another, if will use this in a class of my project in VIsual Studio, to select the data in vertical, this will work?
this works in command line:
select * from tabtest_test where name like '%99%' \G;
now i want use this in a class of my project that I connected with mysql by ODBC.